# How to install OpenCV 3.1 for Python 3.5 On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, python3, opencv

How to install OpenCV version 3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to work with Python 3.5.1?

I tried [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide) on a VM but obviously that is useful to do if you want to work with Python 2.

Comment: is this tagged [windows] because you're using WSL? Please do tell us about your Ubuntu version/environment, otherwise it's hard to diagnose the problem accurately

Comment: Best I've seen so far that worked for me: https://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: This is perfect: https://www.begueradj.com/how-to-install-opencv-4.0-for-python3.6.5-on-ubuntu-18.04-lts/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have OpenCV version 3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to work with Python 3.5.1. At the latest version it's fixed, try:

http://cyaninfinite.com/tutorials/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-for-python-3/

But I didn't download dev python and OpenCV, I took directly from github:

[image: 1]

**EDIT:**

Here are the instructions I tested successfully and mentioned in the link above:

1. Update the repository: `sudo apt-get update`
2. Download the required packages to compile OpenCV:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
   ```
3. Install the developer packages for Python3.5: `sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev`
4. Copy the dev files:`python3.5-config --includes` The output should be similar to: `-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.5m`. The first part of the output is the expected location & the second part shows the current location of the config file. To solve this problem, we’ll copy the file from the current location to the expected location: `sudo cp /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.5m/pyconfig.h /usr/include/python3.5m/`
5. Create a temporary directory, move into it and run: `git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git`. This will download OpenCV 3.  Then rename the folder `opencv` to `opencv-3`
6. Create a `build` directory, move to it and run:

   ```
   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../opencv-3
   ```
7. After the process is finished, run `make` and then `sudo make install`.
8. Enjoy.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of this still fails for me. I get errors n the way about apt_pkg and cannot import multiarray

Comment: In particular it keeps finding python3.4 rather than python3.5 and I have no idea how to direct it to use python3.5. When I tried import opencv in python3.4 I did get a different error about some of the missing dependencies

Comment: The last bit of the last command should be ../../opencv-3 I think... you are two dirs up from specifying the opencv-3 directory

Comment: You also want to use all processors when doing `make`, so if you have 8 cores do `make -j8`

Comment: Execute cmake from another parallel directory else you will get this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518317/in-source-builds-are-not-allowed-in-cmake?rq=1

Answer (score 47):

I found [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python).

OpenCV on wheels.

> Unofficial OpenCV packages for Python.

Installation was painless for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Check the installation:

```
python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.2.0'
```

Comment: I like this solution but got this error message:
`Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement opencv-python`

Comment: This might be the simplest, working solution, unless you're looking for a higher version of opencv

Comment: make sure to use pip3 and NOT pip !

Comment: Was also missing the following in my lxc container: 
apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev

Comment: easy but this package doesn't has video functionalities

Answer (score 11):

python3-opencv can be installed from the [Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) in Ubuntu 17.10 and later. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

[Upgrade your OS to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036930/cannot-install-ubuntu-18-04-wsl/1042949#1042949) if you are using Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04. If Ubuntu 16.04 is installed in WSL `sudo do-release-upgrade` will upgrade it to 18.04.

Comment: Indeed, [no need to install OpenCV separately anymore](https://opencv.org/opencv-python-is-now-an-official-opencv-project/)

Answer (score 2):

The most simple and elegant way I found online is to install the library by running an installation script. Download the [installation script `install-opencv.sh`](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh), open your terminal and execute:

```
bash install-opencv.sh
```

Type your sudo password and you will have installed OpenCV. This operation may take a long time due to the packages to be installed and the compilation process.

The reference: https://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working with Google VM (ubuntu 14.04). Installing opencv on python3.4 version has been quite a task. I wanted opencv to be installed for python 3.4 but every time it was getting installed on 2.7 version.

I will share the steps I followed so as to help others on it.

**Step 1** Follow all the steps as mentioned on openCv installation part till cmake. Link is given below:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Note: Install all the 3 packages mentioned at start. That optional one too..!! And don't forget to change the python version for which you are installing.

I did

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

Follow step 2 for `cmake`.

**Step 2** For installing opencv in specific version of python (ubuntu), you have to set the default (PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE) with the path to where your python is installed. You can find that out by using command whereis python3.4 (or, your version). Mine was in `/usr/bin/python3.4`

Instead of cmake mentioned on the page, use this,

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.4 ..
```

Note: Don't forget to change your python version and path in PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE.

**Step 3** Follow the remaining steps as mentioned in the link till sudo make install

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Base guide: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

The following, tested on **Ubuntu 18.04**, installs **OpenCV 4.1.0-dev** and does not use python virtual environment. I haven't figured out how they work yet. I put the answer here so it has wider visibility.

## Requirements

```
[compiler] sudo apt-get install build-essential
[required] sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
[optional] sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

How to install jasper: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8622#issuecomment-353761271

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libjasper1 libjasper-dev
```

### 1. Clone repos

The installation will include contrib modules.

```
cd ~/<my_working_directory>
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
```

(Git branch to 3.4 to install that version.)

### 1.1 Make build folder

If you mess up, just [delete build folder and start over from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9680493/3163618).

```
mkdir build
cd build
```

### 2. Configuring

I use the following cmake flags:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

Optional flags: (there are [a lot of flags](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), see [this blog post](http://amritamaz.net/blog/opencv-config) for some useful ones)

```
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON 
-DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON 
-DWITH_TBB=ON 
-DWITH_V4L=ON 
-DWITH_QT=ON 
-DWITH_OPENGL=ON
-DWITH_NVCUVID=ON 
-DWITH_CUDA=ON
-DWITH_OPENMP=ON 
-DWITH_IPP=ON
-DWITH_OPENCL=ON
```

Ensure cmake finds your python version by checking its output for the following:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.15)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.15+)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
--     install path:                lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2/python-2.7
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.8)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.8)
--     numpy:                       /home/jx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.15.4)
--     install path:                lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6
```

[How to specify which python versions to use](https://askubuntu.com/q/1024763/477026)

### 3. Make and install

Use make with the desired number of threads (ex. number of processors) then install.

```
make -j8
sudo make install
```

Things should now install to `/usr/local`

### 4. Test

If all went well then you should be able to import cv2 in python.

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV can be installed using pip/pip3 and homebrew. I've tried installing it before using pip3 (Python 3.6.0), but i had problems with VideoCapture, which requires the ffmpeg package. cv2.VideoCapture('videofilename'). This is why I used homebrew for installing OpenCV. Open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
brew install ffmpeg
brew install opencv3 --with-ffmpeg -v (Python 2.7)
brew install opencv3 --with-python3 --with-ffmpeg -v (Python 3.6)
```

Comment: Why do you suggest using `homebrew`?

Comment: OpenCV can be installed using pip/pip3 and homebrew.

I had installed using pip3 (Python 3.6.0), but i had problems with VideoCapture , which requires ffmpeg package.

cv2.VideoCapture('videofilename')

So i used homebrew for installing and it worked well.

Comment: @Biranchi please update your answer with the information from your comment (and maybe add some more information).