# How to install OpenCV3 for Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, python3, cmake, opencv

I have tried installing OpenCV from source. It installs perfectly for python 2.7 and python 3.5, but isn't installing for python 3.6.

I built it using the following command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6 ..
```

The output shows:

```
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
--     numpy:                       /home/courts/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3
```

And when I `make install` the OpenCV library becomes present in the dist-packages folder for python3.5, but not python3.6.

This is in the build log:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.6 (found suitable version "3.6.2", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.2", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (found suitable exact version "3.5.2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I listed all the compiler flags by running:

```
cmake -L | awk '{if(f)print} /-- Cache values/{f=1}'
```

Using the flags that looked helpful, I constructed this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ \
      -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6 \
      -D PYTHON_INCLUDE=/usr/include/python3.6/ \
      -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/python3.6/ \
      -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ \
      -D PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/ \
      ..
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

After following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/262267) first to install Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16 you will have to do the following to get OpenCV compiled *only* for Python 3.6. This has been tested for OpenCV 3.4.3.

```
curl -L https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.3.zip -o opencv.zip
curl -L https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.3.zip -o opencvContrib.zip
unzip -q opencvContrib.zip
unzip -q opencv.zip && cd opencv-3.4.3/ && mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -DBUILD_opencv_python3=yes \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/ \
        -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-3.4.3/modules \
        -DPYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.6 \
        -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE=/usr/include/python3.6/ \
        -DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m \
        -DPYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so \
        -DPYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ \
        -DPYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packageis/numpy/core/ \
        -DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
make -j 4 && make install && cd / && rm opencv.zip && rm opencvContrib.zip && rm -rf opencv-3.4.3/
```